# .NET Serialization Conversion on the Fly

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a node that contains delimited values in an xml file which I am deserializing(System.Xml.Serialization) to a class.

This is a sample of the XML data element node:

```
<Data>1,2,3,4,8,11<Data>
```

Is it possible to split the integer data during the deserialization process so that the string of data gets converted into a list of property like the following:

```
List<int> Data {get; set;}
```

Comment: Why are you using xml to store comma separated values? Aren't you getting the worst of two worlds this way?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using LINQ to XML for serialization, but if you use `System.Xml.Serialization` you could perform this by using a custom setter for a `String` property that splits the string and fills the `List` property.

```
List listData {get; set;}
String Data
{
    get
    {
       return String.Empty;
    }
    set
    {
        listData.AddRange(value.Split(','));
    }
}
```

**AFTER Munim's EDIT**

After Minim added the generic `<int>`, the setter should be like this:

```
set
{
    string[] temp = value.Split(',');
    foreach (string s in temp)
        listData.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s));
}
```